# Need help for writing a SQL query in Sequelize using NODEJS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two SQL queries which i am having trouble with converting to Sequelieze Queries.
I have a model named UserTeam having columns id,team_id and isAdmin.

The first query  is

```
Select distinct('team_id') from UserTeam where id==user.id and idAdmin==true
```

The second one is similar by with a little addition of group by

```
Select count('isAdmin') from UserTeam where id==user.id group by 'team_id';
```

I have written this but is incorrect:

```
const teamsMember = await  UserTeam.findAll({where: { id: user.id, isAdmin : true}, sequelize.fn('distinct', sequelize.col('UserTeam.team_id'))});

const adminCount = await UserTeam.findAll({where: {id: user.id }, sequelize.fn('count',sequelize.col('isAdmin')), group: ['UserTeam.team_id']]});
```

And is there any way to get the generated query from these sequelize queries?